# lavalamp jquery not linking through

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, hyperlink, lavalamp

I'm struggling getting my lavalamp to work on a site i'm redesigning. the jquery and links were taken from the previous site but they're not working when you click on them.

note all pages aren't finished yet, about us page is live on the site to check

[www.alwaystwisted.com/sandbox/stagecraft/index.html](http://www.alwaystwisted.com/sandbox/stagecraft/index.html)

any ideas?

I'm sure it's something simple, but still too complext for me.

thanks in advance

Stu

Comment: for those who (like me) don't know what the jQuery lavalamp is: http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your returning false when the link has been clicked!

```
 $("#1, #2, #3").lavaLamp({
                fx: "backout", 
                speed: 600,
                click: function(event, menuItem) {
                    //this stops the link from following
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: this helped, thanks
I'm a bit curious though why the author would have put the click function in?

Answer (score 1):

just replace the "false" with "true"

So it will be return true;

Comment: where exactly this should happen?

Answer (score 1):

doesn't deleting the line

```
"return false;"
```

also fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it solves the problem:

```
var $tlt = jQuery.noConflict();
$tlt(function() {
    $tlt('.lavamenu').lavalamp( ... );


});
```