# JavaScript Scroller Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, dhtml

I want to make  a horizontal menu that has an arrow over it that scrolls with the mouse cursor. The example: http://cartubank.ge . Does anyone have the source code for that?

I'd really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is like [LavaLamp jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4799959/jquery-sliding-arrow-under-menu). Look at the example in following link.

- [LavaLamp for jQuery lovers!](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/#tb)
- [jQuery LavaLamp Demos - a jQuery animated menu plugin](http://nixboxdesigns.com/projects/jquery-lavalamp/demos/original.html#PhoneHome)

But you have to play with it to change it according to your desired design.

Comment: Thanks for the LavaLamp, when testing it turned out that the link isn't clickable, I mean,

Comment: I mean, there's a link in <a href="...  and when I hover, browser displays a link but while clicking it does nothing, any ideas?

Comment: @Mikey: Oh.. I did not try it. I think you should try it and ask another question with some code that you have tried so far. At the moment I cant understand your problem...

Answer (score 2):

it's a jquery plugin called "[lava lamp](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/)". 
there is also a pure javascript version by [Michael leigeber](http://www.scriptiny.com/2008/05/sliding-javascript-menu-highlight-1kb/)

Comment: thanks for answer... I have a question to you... I noticed that links on LavaLamp aren't clickable. I mean you can write link into <a href=""  tag, when you hover the menu item you can see the link but you can't click it. when you click any of menu items - it does nothing. I doesn't work as a proper menu item. maybe you could tell me what the problem might be.

Comment: @NAVEED  - I found the problem. it was on StackOverflow... [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322902/lavalamp-jquery-not-linking-through)  the author has put return False, it should be return true